# Getting answer in object form after using array_diff

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, array-difference

I am comparing 2 arrays but after applying array_diff it returns the result in the object form.
Have a look at the below code and result

```
<?php
        $schedule =  ['Monday'=>['12:00','01:20'],'Tuesday'=>['04:00','12:00','20:00']];
        $booked_slots =  ['Monday'=>['12:00'],'Tuesday'=>['20:00']];
        
        $diff = [];
        foreach ($schedule as $day =>  $times) {
            $day_wise_slots = isset($booked_slots[$day]) ? $booked_slots[$day] : [];
            $diff[$day] = array_diff($times, $day_wise_slots);
        }
        
        echo json_encode($diff);
?>
```

Result : {"Monday":{"1":"01:20"},"Tuesday":["04:00","12:00"]}

Desired Output: {"Monday":["01:20"],"Tuesday":["04:00","12:00"]}

Comment: The indexes need to be contiguous and start from 0. Run [`array_values()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-values.php) on the result of `array_diff()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`array_diff` perserves keys of original array. You need to reinitialize array to not have array keys in json. You can use `array_values` to get a reinitialized  array keys

```
<?php
       $schedule =  ['Monday'=>['12:00','01:20'],'Tuesday'=>['04:00','12:00','20:00']];
       $booked_slots =  ['Monday'=>['12:00'],'Tuesday'=>['20:00']];
       
       $diff = [];
       foreach ($schedule as $day =>  $times) {
           $day_wise_slots = isset($booked_slots[$day]) ? $booked_slots[$day] : [];
           $diff[$day] = array_values(array_diff($times, $day_wise_slots));
       }
       
       echo json_encode($diff);
?>
```